# react component state is not updating with callback

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

Cannot update state in closeTab method when state loaded from cache. closeTabis triggered by child. I have tried cache state with {...this.state},Object.Assign(), json.stringify()then json.parse but no luck. Is there alternative method to set state from cache and make possible to work as expected (possible to close when state loaded from the cache)?

```
 class XPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    if (iwb.debugConstructor)
      if (iwb.debug) console.log("XPage.constructor", props);
    super(props);
    document.getElementById("id-breed").innerHTML = this.props.grid.name;
    iwb.killGlobalSearch();
    var oldPageState = iwb.pages[props.grid.id];
    this.convertToArr = (invalidTabs)=>{
      let validTab = [];
      invalidTabs.forEach(item=>{
        validTab.push({
          name: item.name,
          icon: item.icon,
          title: item.title,
          value: {...item.value},
        })
      })
      return validTab;
    }
    if (oldPageState) {
      this.state = {
        activeTab : oldPageState.activeTab,
        tabs:this.convertToArr(oldPageState.tabs)
      };
      this.dontRefresh = true;
    } else {
      this.state = {
        activeTab: "x",
        tabs: [
          { name: "x", icon: "icon-list", title: "Liste", value: props.grid }
        ]
      };
    }
    /**
     * @description
     * a Function to toggle between tabs
     * @param {Event} event - click event from tab
     */
    this.toggle = event => {
      var activeTab = event.target ? event.target.getAttribute("name") : event;
      if (this.state.activeTab !== activeTab) {
        var { tabs } = this.state;
        tabs &&
          tabs.forEach(tempTab => {
            if (tempTab.name === activeTab) {
              this.setState({ activeTab });
              return true;
            }
          });
      }
      return false;
    };
    this.isActionInTabList = action => {
      var { tabs } = this.state;
      var stopToFetch = false;
      tabs &&
        tabs.forEach(tempTab => {
          if (tempTab.name === action) {
            this.toggle(action);
            stopToFetch = true;
          }
        });
      return stopToFetch;
    };
    /**
     * @description
     * A function responsible for opening tab getting component from the server and evaluating it on the page
     * @param {String} action - ['1-&toffer_id=4'] EditForm satrts 1-* , InsertForm satrts 2-*
     * @param {String} url - ['showForm?a=1&_fid=3988&twork_position_id=1']
     * @param {Object} params - a variable which holds request body params
     * @param {Object} callAttributes - [{modal:false}] a variable used to pass params to a component which comes from the server
     */
    this.openTab = (action, url, params, callAttributes) => {
      if (this.state.activeTab !== action) {
        if (this.isActionInTabList(action)) return;
        fetch(url, {
          body: JSON.stringify(params || {}), // must match 'Content-Type' header
          cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
          credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
          headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
          method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
          mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
          redirect: "follow", // *manual, follow, error
          referrer: "no-referrer" // *client, no-referrer
        })
          .then(
            response =>
              response.status === 200 || response.status === 0
                ? response.text()
                : Promise.reject(
                    new Error(response.text() || response.statusText)
                  )
          )
          .then(
            result => {
              if (result) {
                var f;
                eval("f=(callAttributes, parentCt)=>{\n" + result + "\n}");
                var serverComponent = f(callAttributes || {}, this);
                if (serverComponent) {
                  if (callAttributes && callAttributes.modal) {
                    //console.log(callAttributes);
                    iwb.showModal({
                      body: serverComponent,
                      size: "lg",
                      title:
                        serverComponent.props && serverComponent.props.cfg
                          ? serverComponent.props.cfg.name
                          : "",
                      color: "primary"
                      //style   :{maxWidth:'90%'}
                    });
                  } else {
                    var plus = action.substr(0, 1) == "2";
                    var { tabs } = this.state;
                    if (this.isActionInTabList(action)) return;
                    tabs.push({
                      name: action,
                      icon: plus ? "icon-plus" : "icon-doc",
                      title: plus ? " Yeni" : " Düzenle",
                      value: serverComponent
                    });
                    this.setState({ activeTab: action, tabs });
                  }
                }
              } else {
                toastr.error("Sonuc Gelmedi", " Error");
              }
            },
            error => {
              toastr.error(error, "Connection Error");
            }
          );
      }
    };
    iwb.openTab = this.openTab;
    /**
     * @description
     * A function responsible for closing tab and
     * delating CurrentTab from the state of Xpage Component
     * this function will be passed to whenever new tab is opened
     */
    this.closeTab = (event, forceRelaod = false) => {
      var { activeTab, tabs } = this.state;
      if (activeTab == "x") return;
      tabs =
        tabs &&
        tabs.length > 0 &&
        tabs.filter(tempTab => tempTab.name !== activeTab);
      if (forceRelaod) {
        tabs["0"].value.forceRelaod = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      }
      this.setState({ activeTab: "x", tabs },() => {
        alert();
      });
    };
    /**
     * @description
     * A function is used to open new FormTab
     * @param {string} url
     */
    this.openForm = (url, callAttributes = {}) => {
      if (url) this.openTab("1-" + Math.random(), url, {}, callAttributes);
      return false;
    };
    iwb.openForm = this.openForm;
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    iwb.killGlobalSearch();
    iwb.pages[this.props.grid.id] = Object.assign({},this.state);
  }
  render() {
    if (iwb.debugRender) if (iwb.debug) console.log("XPage.render");
    return _(
      "div",
      {},
      _(
        Row,
        null,
        _(
          Col,
          { className: "mb-4" },
          _(
            Nav,
            { tabs: true, hidden: this.state.tabs.length == 1 },
            this.state.tabs.map(({ name, icon, title }, index) => {
              return _(
                NavItem,
                { key: "NavItem" + index },
                _(
                  NavLinkS,
                  {
                    className: classNames({
                      active: this.state.activeTab === name
                    }),
                    name,
                    onClick: event => this.toggle(event)
                  },
                  _("i", {
                    className: icon,
                    name,
                    title,
                    onClick: event => this.toggle(event)
                  }),
                  title && name != "x" && this.state.activeTab === name && title
                )
              );
            })
          ),
          _(
            TabContent,
            { activeTab: this.state.activeTab },
            this.state.tabs.map(({ name, value }, index) => {
              return _(
                TabPane,
                { key: "TabPane" + index, tabId: name },
                value.gridId
                  ? _(XMainGrid, {
                      openTab: this.openTab,
                      closeTab: this.closeTab,
                      ...value
                    })
                  : value
              );
            })
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```